# PHP Combine Arrays By Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays:

```
    [review] => Array
    (
        [14829] => 0
        [14840] => 1
        [14844] => 1
        [14846] => 0
    )
```

And

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idRequisition] => 14829
            [idDpt] => 118
            [account] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idRequisition] => 14829
            [idDpt] => 118
            [account] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,02
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,03
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,04
        )

)
```

I need to combine both, but every value of `review` (0 or 1) must match in the 2nd array. The final result must be like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [review] => 0
            [idRequisition] => 14829
            [idDpt] => 118
            [account] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [review] => 0
            [idRequisition] => 14829
            [idDpt] => 118
            [account] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [review] => 1
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [review] => 1
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,02
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [review] => 1
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,03
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [review] => 1
            [idRequisition] => 14844
            [idDpt] => 43
            [account] => 3101020101
            [value] => R$ 0,04
        )

)
```

Comment: i think you have two different table and you  retrieving the table value by two different select statement. if so go for joins. don't make it complicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `review` contains in `$review` array and your array contains in `$array`:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value['review'] = $review[$value['idRequisition']];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, pal, fast and precise. You saved my day.